# How to access the width of a Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, attributes

I want to change the width of an object depending on how large the user makes the window for my Visual Studio Form. The code I have is:

```
webBrowser1.Width = Form1.Width - 42;
```

And Visual Studio says "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: Form1 is a type, not a variable like webBrowser1.  Surely you meant `this.ClientSize.Width`

Comment: Thanks! The error is gone! I just don't know where to put that code.

Answer (score 0):

The `Width` is an instance member of the `Form1` class. So you can call it using a `Form1` instance like this:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
var newWidth1 = myForm.Width - 42 // Calling instance member from an instance - Correct
var newWidth2 = Form1.Width - 42  // Calling instance member from a class - Incorrect
```

Comment: I don't see how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

The width of a form is not a static member of the form, so you have to call it through the instance of the form. So you actually need the object of your form to access the width. This is just logical, as you could create multiple instances of your form with different sizes.

---

For the implementation:

Your form is started in some point of your program. So what you could've wrote is:

```
new Form1().Show();
```

or if the form is the startup form of a WinForms application it is started in `Program.cs`:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

What you could do is to save the instance of the form in a variable:

```
var yourForm = new Form1();
yourForm.Show();
```

Now you could access the forms width:

```
webBrowser1.Width = yourForm.Width - 42;
```

---

Another possibility would be to save the width in a static property in your form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static int UniversalWidth;
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        UniversalWidth = Width;
    }
//...
```

Now you could access the Width through the `UniversalWidth` field:

```
webBrowser1.Width = Form1.UniversalWidth;
```

However, I wouldn't recommend to use this, as it won't work if you have multiple windows of the form open.

---

As I don't know your whole project, it could be possible that the code is actually written inside your Form1 class. Then you could of course access the width like that:

```
webBrowser1.Width = this.Width;
```

Or, if you want to access the size from another class, you could give this class the form through the constructor:

```
var otherClass = new yourOtherClass (this);
```

Then the others class constructor could look like this:

```
public yourOtherClass (Form1 yourForm)
{
    webBrowser1.Width = yourForm.Width;
}
```

---

For more precise information, please provide more precise information.

Comment: @JacobBates did this help you? If it solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as an answer, as this will help you and the wider community to identify solved problems.